# Query specific field in Firestore snapshot

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I created this stream that gets a snapshot of a specific document. Inside the document theres an array called tripAttractions that I want to build into a list. The question is, how do I access this specific array from the snapshot?

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getAttractions(BuildContext context) async* {
   Firestore.instance
      .collection('trips')
      .document(documentId)
      .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true);

}
```

The list shows how I'm trying to access the snapshot tripAttractions data but this doesn't work.

```
ListView.builder(
   itemCount: snapshot.data['tripAttractions'].length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                        tripAttractionsCards(
                            context, index, snapshot.data['tripAttractions']),
                  );
```

Array inside the firestore document
[image: flutter]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the issue was that incorrectly called **QuerySnapshot**. I'm supposed to use **DocumentSnapshot** since I'm calling a document directly. Also I had to add **yield*** to return the data from firestore.

```
Stream<DocumentSnapshot> getAttractions(BuildContext context) async* {
   yield* Firestore.instance
      .collection('trips')
      .document(documentId)
      .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true);
}
```

I was able to troubleshoot this by checking if the snapshot was sending any data by adding an if statement inside the streamBuilder.

```
   if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text("Loading");
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're just missing the array accessor in the item builder:

```
ListView.builder(
   itemCount: snapshot.data['tripAttractions'].length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
            tripAttractionsCards(
                context, index, snapshot.data['tripAttractions'][index]),
      );
```

Comment: Hey Frank! I tried doing this but I get the following error: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null, Tried Calling: []("tripAttractions")

Comment: Interesting: you might want to check what `snapshot.data` is doing for you then, as it seems you're trying to get data from an empty or non-existing snapshot.

Comment: I just created an if statement to check and the snapshot query is not returning any data

Comment: Thanks I figured out the issue! I will post what I was doing wrong

Comment: Thanks again Frank! Second time you have saved me with my project.